# Re-enabling event.preventDefault();

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

I have been searching for ages for a solution to this problem, I am aware that there is no restore default solution type of thing. However here is my problem.

```
$('#signInbtn').click(function(event) {
    checkLogInForm(event);
});
```

this checks the login in fields to confirm they are not left blank, like so:

```
function checkLogInForm(event) {
    var usernameValid, passwordValid = false;
    checkUsername(usernameValid);
    checkPassword(passwordValid);
    if (!passwordValid || !usernameValid) {
        event.preventDefault();
    } else {
        $('#signInbtn').unbind('submit');
    }
}
```

However the numerous solutions I have tried never result in the form actually submitting when the else is triggered. Any ideas how I can resume/submit the default behaviour? or even an alternative approach. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle of your problem. So you say you do get in the `else` bit but the form doesn't submit.

Comment: Yeah that is correct.

Comment: Post your HTML (and a fiddle would help).

Comment: Does your form tag have an id? if so, could you try `document.getElementById("my_form_id").submit();` after your unbind call?

Comment: vch - This has worked for me! my else clause has document.getElementById("signInForm").submit(); 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luhring/7j1dobpa/)

One solution would be to evaluate whether the preventDefault action should be applied:

```
/** 
*      toggle status if preventDefaultStatus is true 
*/
function updateStatus(preventDefaultStatus) {
     return (preventDefaultStatus === true) ? false : true;
}

/** 
*      toggle preventDefault
*/
function toggleDefault(isActive) {

    submitElement.onclick = function(e){

        if(isActive === true){

            e.preventDefault();

        }
    }       
}

/**
*      trigger toggleDefault and updateStatus
*/
function update(){
    toggleDefault(status);
    status = updateStatus(status);
}


exampleButton.onclick = update;


(function(){
    update();
})();
```

(written in pure javascript to clarify that this applies regardless of whether or not you're using jQuery)
In jQuery, you would just replace the onclick handlers with .click(function(e){})

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'submit' event with the form id or form name as the jQuery selector for example:

```
$('#signInForm').submit(function(event) {
    checkLogInForm(event);
});
```

Your checkLogInForm(event) method can leave the else statement out if the form should be submitted.